# A confusion about iterated limits - What would be a rigourous definition?

Tags: limits, continuity

The Dirichlet function is the indicator function $1_ℚ$ of the set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $1_\mathbb{Q}(x) = 1$ if $x$ is a rational number and $1_\mathbb{Q}(x) = 0$ if $x$ is not a rational number (i.e. an irrational number).
What the professor asks to show is that :

$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R},   1_\mathbb{Q}(x)= \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}(\lim_{m \rightarrow +\infty} |\cos(n!\pi x )|^m) $$

It seemed at first clear why the previous equality is true. But then it  raised this question in my head:

About iterated limits, taking a simple example, is it true to say the following?
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}(\lim_{m \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{n}{m}) = 0  \ \ \text{but} \ \ \lim_{m \rightarrow +\infty}(\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{n}{m}) = +\infty$$
Another example:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}(\lim_{m \rightarrow +\infty} (1 +\frac{1}{n})^m) = +\infty  \ \ \text{and} \ \ \lim_{m \rightarrow +\infty}(\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} (1 +\frac{1}{n})^m) = 1 \\ \text{whereas} \ \ \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} (1 +\frac{1}{n})^n = e  $$

I hope I have been clear in my presentation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure why this got a -1, this is a very reasonable point to be worried about. (That said, it's not clear what this question has to do with your professor's exercise.)

Comment: Hi Noah, the following part that has to do with the professor exercise is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044332/a-confusion-about-iterated-limits-what-would-be-a-rigourous-definition-part. I needed your enlightenment first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - in general, **the order in which we take limits matters**. There are situations where limits commute (= order doesn't matter) but this should never be taken for granted.

Division is a bit of an odd case because we have to worry about dividing by zero; the issue already crops up with *subtraction*. We have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\lim_{y\rightarrow+\infty}x-y=-\infty\quad\mbox{but}\quad \lim_{y\rightarrow+\infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}x-y=+\infty.$$

Both of your examples are right, but I think this is an easier one to start off with.